How to login correctly to Microsoft 365 on Ubuntu 24.04
I just installed ubuntu 24.04 LTS on my laptop, when i tried to connect Microsoft 365 using new features of ubuntu. Initially i was asked to log in my microsoft account using browser, but when i get to step just open the configuration pop up, there's nothing happen.

it just stuck like nothing happen


Does this help? https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/05/fix-ubuntu-onedrive-account-error and https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/set-up-onedrive-file-access-in-ubuntu
